# obtener value a un post en form

Tags: php

Chicos una pequeña duda, por favor gracias tengo una consulta y obtengo el valor

```
<textarea name="autor"  id="autor" style="width: 100%;   min-height: 28px;" value="<?php echo $row["Autor"]; ?>" disabled><?php echo $row["Autor"]; ?></textarea>
```

Y lo mando en un form

`<form action="InsertaArticulo3.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Ahora en InsertarArticulo3 recupero el valor pero está vacío

```
$titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
$articulo= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['articulo']);

$autor=$_POST['autor'];
```

Por favor me pueden ayudar no entiendo el valor viene vacio y los nombres están bien, antes si insertaba pero desde que metí ese value ya no lo inserta en la base :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que tu textarea tiene el atributo `disabled` y no se enviara su valor, intenta con `readonly`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted

Comment: Resuelto era eso gracias